# Can monodevelop do Web.config transformations like no VS2010

Tags: asp.net, mono, monodevelop

It's very important to have Web.config transformations when we want to avoid errors while publishing for staging or production. Can this be done using monodevelop? I've search for a solution without any success.

Comment: Also interested, can't see much on this online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not currently (as of 2.10.9). Mono does not yet have an implementation of MSDeploy, and specifically the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll assembly and the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets file.

Answer (score 6):

I'm answering after a long time in case someone finds this question.
I have developed a way to publish a ASP.NET project through *xbuild* (not directly through Monodevelop) **with** Web.config transformations.
You can find it [here](http://mzabani.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/mono-asp-net-project-deployment-with-web-config-xdt-transformations/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets` NuGet package , see [TransformXml task fails via msbuild on linux using mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097944/transformxml-task-fails-via-msbuild-on-linux-using-mono/45097945#45097945) for full instructions.