# TransformXml task fails via msbuild on linux using mono

Tags: c#, msbuild, mono

After following the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109530/4875631), when attempting to build a project through mono (Using msbuild), I get the following error:

> (AfterCompile target) ->
>     project.csproj(469,5): error MSB4062: The "TransformXml" task could not be loaded from the assembly /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/Web/Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll.  Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

It appears as if `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll` is unavailable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On linux via mono, this file doesn't exist. To solve this issue, follow these steps:

1. Install the nuget package MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets
2. Right click your project, and click "Unload Project"
3. Right click your (now unloaded) project, and click "Edit MyProjectName.csproj"
4. Replace this line:

```xml
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
```

With your updated nuget `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll` location (Update version name in `MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3` as necessary):

```xml
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="..\packages\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
```

5. Reload your project, and voila, working build on linux!

Comment: This solution was my rescue more than 3 years later, thank you so much!

Comment: I had to add <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="..\packages\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" /> to .csproj as it was not present yet.

Comment: This worked for me on OSX except that I had to drop the initial `..\ ` from the `AssemblyFile` property, so `<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="packages\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />`